# How to check the memory available in LruCache of android?

Tags: android, caching, memory, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

I want to use memory cache(LruCache) instead of DiskLruCache for caching the images. I have some doubts regarding the image Caching in android.

How can i check the available memory size in Lrucache?

What does happen when the caching request crosses the Available memory in Lrucache?

Is the LruCache object retain in dalvik heap memory? or caching done is kept in heap memory?

Comment: do you want to caching bitmap (ImageView)?

Comment: Hi blaze, yes i want to cache the bitmap.

Comment: Like i said earlier, i dont understand about LruCache. However, you can use Picasso or Universal Image Loader library that automatically work with caching

Comment: Check out volley's code, they have implementations for MemoryCache, and DiskLruCache (http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Does LruCache clears the memory when there is no space for another bitmap caching?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to first question:

```
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
    //...
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    int availMemInBytes = am.getMemoryClass() * 1024 * 1024;
```

Answer to the second:

The Least Recently Used object(s) will be removed from the list. One or more objects will be removed till there will be enough space to put the new object.

About the third question I think I'm late since Dalvik is not anymore used for Android > 4.4.2. Maybe this video can help to figure out what happens with the new ART 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJDPXCTt5TLDu67271PruEk&t=47&v=R5ON3iwx78M

I hope it will help.